# Generate a specific range of IP address in MS.Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to generate a specific range of IP from `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.255.255`

How can I do that job in Microsoft Excel?

I used these formulas, but not work for all range of IP address:

```
Excel IP Addresses Increment the Third Octet
="10.1."&ROWS($A$1:A1)&".1"
Excel IP Addresses Increment the Fourth Octet
="10.1.1."&ROWS($A$1:A1)
```

Comment: You should be able to do so using 3 loops. `First loop:` run the fourth octet from 0 to 255 - `Second loop:` once the fourth octet reaches 255, reset the variable for the fourth octet to 0 and add 1 to the variable for the third octet - `Third loop:` when your variable for the third octet reaches 255, exit the loop. Structure being `third loop>second loop>first loop`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your starting IP address is 10.1.1.1. That is 0A010101 IN HEX. Put that in a cell, let's say A2. Put this formula in B2,

```
=HEX2DEC(LEFT(A2, 2))&"."&HEX2DEC(MID(A2, 3, 2))&"."&HEX2DEC(MID(A2, 5, 2))&"."&HEX2DEC(RIGHT(A2, 2))
```

Now put this formula in A3,

```
=DEC2HEX(HEX2DEC(A2)+1, 8)
```

Copy the formula from B2 to B3 then fill A3:B3 down as far as you want.

[image: IP Addresses]

Comment: Btw, 192.168.1.0 is C0A50100.

Answer (score 1):

here's an elementary solution

in `A1` put 1000 for starting at `1.0` or 0 for srating at `0.0`

in `A2` put `=A1+IF(MOD(A1,1000)<255,1,745)`

in `B1` put `="192.168." & QUOTIENT(A1,1000) & "." & MOD(A1,1000)` (of course the `"192.168."` part is your first two octet, modify it to taste)

copy the formula from `B1` to `B2` then fill `A2:B2` down and voilà.